# How to resolve this error erb is throwing when passing a currency formatted string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a module within my Rails App to perform some actions and render a html file and save it to S3. So far so good, apart from the fact that I need to pass a currency variable to to be rendered and erb is throwing this error:

```
undefined method `/' for "3,395,000":String
```

Here's my code:

```
options = {
  ...
  price: Money.new(@case.cash_price / 100.to_i, "DKK").format.to_s.html_safe,
  ...
}
```

And here's my module:

```
def generate_html(options)
  require 'erb'

  erb_file = "templates/banners/widesky.html.erb"

  erb_str = File.read(erb_file)

  ...
  @price = options[:price]
  ...

  renderer = ERB.new(erb_str)
  result = renderer.result(binding)

  FileUtils.mkdir_p('temp') unless File.directory?('temp')

  File.open('temp/index.html', 'w') do |f|
    f.write(result)
  end

  'temp/index.html'

end
```

And I tried formatting the currency in different ways, but I always get the same error. Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

`@case.cash_price` originally is an Integer. I want to convert it to a string with commas (hence using Money to format it). The problem seems to be that `erb` doesn't like the formatted result and throw the above error.

Comment: is `@case.cash_price` the string it complains about?

Comment: I'm assuming so for two reasons: 1) if I remove it, everything works ok. 2) the value I'm passing to it is "3,395,000" (without the formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot use any gem/helper, let's reinvent the wheel!

```
def to_currency(price_in_cents, currency=nil, decimal_separator = '.', thousand_separator = ',')
  price_in_cents.to_s.rjust(3,'0').reverse.insert(2,decimal_separator).gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\1'+thousand_separator).reverse+(currency ? " #{currency}" : '')
end

puts to_currency(123456789, 'DKK')
puts to_currency(123456, '€', ',', ' ')
puts to_currency(1)
```

It outputs :

```
1,234,567.89 DKK
1 234,56 €
0.01
```

Note that price_in_cents should be either a String that looks like an Integer ("123456789") or an Integer (123456789), but not a preformatted String ("123,456.78") or a Float (1.23).
Finally, the resulting String is as unsafe as price_in_cents :

```
to_currency("unsafe_codejs")
=> "unsafe_code.js"
```

You don't have to specify html_safe on the result anyway, because nothing would be escaped in "1,234,567.89 DKK".

Original answer :

If cash_price is a String with commas, you need to remove the commas first, then convert it to a float, then divide by 100, and then convert the result to an Integer.
cash_price.to_s is to avoid getting errors if cash_price does come as a Numeric.

```
price: Money.new((@case.cash_price.to_s.delete(',').to_f/100).to_i, "DKK").format.to_s.html_safe
```

Comment: To the down-voter : Would you please care to explain why? As far as I can tell, this example should work. If it doesn't, please provide more feedback.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but did you downvote me? Your rep went down as you posted this

Comment: You lost 3 points. When you get downvoted, you lose 2. When you downvote, you lose 1

Comment: I work on multiple questions in //. I didn't agree with the accepted answer for a Java question.

Comment: Both of your answers also look right to me and then I saw the comments so I cared to upvote both.

Comment: As per my edit, `@case.cash_price` is already an Integer. I want to format it to something like this: 3.000,00, hence me using the Money gem, however when I try to render the template, erb throws the error. Please note I've also tried format it using `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` and `number_to_currency(@case.cash_price)`

Comment: What was the problem with number_to_currency?

Answer (score 0):

`@case.cash_price` is a string so you can't perform any mathematical operations on it. You would need to convert the value to an integer (3395000) rather than a comma delimited string as you currently have ('3,395,000').

A side note, `100.to_i` is redundant as `100` is already an integer, unless you wanted to convert the equation to an integer, which would need brackets `(@case.cash_price / 100).to_i`.